# Returning a set of particular records via explode PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to match a particular set of records relevant to a user. For instance, I am trying to grab all of the groups that a user is a part of by checking if their username is a part of the `group_members` field. I'm using the PHP `explode` function, but it is only returning the part after the delimiter. I want the match to be retrieved.

Here is my code:

```
$select = new Select('groups');

$select->columns(array('group_members'))
->where("group_name != '' AND group_name IS NOT NULL");

$query = parent::$sql->getAdapter()->query(
    parent::$sql->buildSqlString($select),
    Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE
);

if (count($query) > 0) {
    $user = array();

        foreach ($query as $value) {
            // determine what groups the user is in
            $user[] = $value['group_members'];
        }

        return $user;

    if (in_array(parent::getUser(), explode(", ", $user))) {
        echo "yay";
    } else {
        throw new GroupsExceptions("No groups were found for " . parent::getUser());
    }
} else {
    throw new GroupsExceptions("Looks like there are no groups created yet! Maybe you would like to create one?");
}
```

here is the var_dump results:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(20) "jimmysole, timlinden" [1]=> string(9) "timlinden" }
```

`parent::getUser()` is the method that is matched to the username and the group members field in the database contains "name, name2".

How would I go about matching and then grabbing only the username that matches the session user? Is there a way to extract "jimmysole" from the first array value only? I can't seem to get it to work right with explode but I think I am probably doing it wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($query as $value) {
    // determine what groups the user is in
    $user = $value['group_members'];
}
```

this is looping the $query array anding adding each to the string $user, as it overwrites on each loop, $user will be the last value from $query

```
if (in_array(parent::getUser(), explode(", ", $user))) {
```

$user is a string here of 1 with no seperator

---

so:

```
foreach ($query as $value) {
    // determine what groups the user is in
    $user[] = $value['group_members'];
}
```

this creates the $user array ..

```
if (in_array(parent::getUser(), $user)) {
```

now use the array. no to change it from a string, when we crate an array in the first place.

Comment: unfortunately that is not finding any records in the database even though they exist.

Comment: is that the In_array part? debug with: `echo parent::getUser();` and `print_r($user);` add those results to your question

Comment: it's in the in_array part. I'm trying to use explode or some other equivalent function to break up the results via a delimiter so I can basically "extract" one single value, and it seemed explode() was the best way to do it..

Comment: as previously stated, you where exploding on a string with only 1 item as you had kept overwriting them in the loop, ad the debugging information requested above.

Comment: $user is an array, there is no need to explode it

Comment: I want to get a particular value in it and the field can contain multiple values, so one array value will have all the names in it and I am trying to only extract the one name that matches the user session name.